# Read image from datatable in asp

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have a Data table which a has a column for images.
I am using the following code to read the image

```
byte[] Logo = (byte[])dt_Info.Rows[0]["Logo"];
```

But it got this error :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

In addition I Save the image binary code in ''bytes".
When I Write this Code , it works correctly.

```
byte[] Logo = bytes;
```

What Should I do to handle the error and read image from Data-table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dt_Info.Rows[0]["Logo"].ToString());
```

Comment: An Other Question.
How i can decode this code when i want to display it?

Comment: byte[] array ={100,10,20,44,333};
string value = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(array);

Answer (score 0):

you can get byte array like this
string s = (string)dt_Info.Rows[0]["Logo"];
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);